# No learning occuring in reinforcement learning agent

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement the deep deterministic gradient method in tensorflow and keras, however, I seem to be stuck. There seems to be no learning occurring, the actions taken by the model do not seem to change at all and the gradient applied to the actor-network is very small as well (on the order of magnitude of e^-5). I have used another implementation as a reference and this one runs very well with the exact same hyperparameters and network architectures (except that it is implemented with tflearn and includes batch normalization layers), making me believe that there is a mistake somewhere in my code. Maybe someone here can spot it.
Thank you for your time!

Edit: I think the reason for the bad performance is that the critic-network's gradient with respect to the action is vanishing. I can't, however, figure out why. Maybe my use of the concatenate layer is wrong?

```
class AIInterface(object):

def __init__(self, sim):

    self.sim = sim

    self.pedal_pos = 0
    self.steering_pos = 0

    self.sess = tf.Session()

    self.learning_rate = 10e-4
    self.BATCH_SIZE = 64
    self.epsilon = .75 #amount of random exploration
    self.epsilon_decay = .997
    self.gamma = .99 #reward discount factor
    self.tau = .00125 #target update factor

    self.rewards = deque(maxlen=100000)
    self.memory = deque(maxlen=100000)

    # Actor stuff
    self.actor_model, self.actor_var_in = self.initialize_actor()
    self.target_actor, _ = self.initialize_actor()

    self.actor_critic_grad = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

    self.actor_model_weights = self.actor_model.trainable_weights

    with tf.name_scope("actor_gradients"):
        self.actor_grads = tf.gradients(self.actor_model.output, self.actor_model_weights, -self.actor_critic_grad)
        self.normalized_actor_grads = list(map(lambda x: tf.div(x, self.BATCH_SIZE), self.actor_grads))

    grads = zip(self.normalized_actor_grads, self.actor_model_weights)
    self.optimize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate).apply_gradients(grads)

    # Critic stuff
    self.critic_model, self.critic_var_in, self.critic_action_in = self.initialize_critic()
    self.target_critic, _, _ = self.initialize_critic()

    with tf.name_scope("CriticGrads"):
        self.critic_grads = tf.gradients(self.critic_model.output, self.critic_action_in)

    self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    self.target_actor.set_weights(self.actor_model.get_weights())
    self.target_critic.set_weights(self.critic_model.get_weights())

    self.global_step = 0

def initialize_actor(self):

    state_variable_input = Input(shape=(3, ))

    init = TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.02)

    dense = Dense(128, activation="relu", kernel_initializer=init)(state_variable_input)
    dense2 = Dense(128, activation="relu", kernel_initializer=init)(dense)

    output = Dense(1, activation="tanh", kernel_initializer=RandomUniform(-3e-3, 3e-3))(dense2)

    model = Model(inputs=state_variable_input,
                  outputs=output)

    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")

    return model, state_variable_input


def initialize_critic(self):

    state_variable_input = Input(shape=(3, ))
    action_input = Input(shape=(1, ))

    init = TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.02)
    dense_state = Dense(128, activation="relu", kernel_initializer=init)(state_variable_input)

    merge = Concatenate()([dense_state, action_input])
    dense2 = Dense(128, activation="relu", kernel_initializer=init)(merge)

    output = Dense(1, activation="linear", kernel_initializer=RandomUniform(-3e-3, 3e-3))(dense2)

    model = Model(inputs=[state_variable_input, action_input],
                  outputs=output)

    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")

    return model, state_variable_input, action_input


def train(self):

    if len(self.memory) < self.BATCH_SIZE:
        return

    samples = random.sample(self.memory, self.BATCH_SIZE)

    samples = [np.concatenate(x) for x in zip(*samples)]

    self.train_critic(samples)
    self.train_actor(samples)
    self.global_step += 1


def train_critic(self, samples):

    cur_state_var, action, reward, new_state_var = samples

    predicted_action = self.target_actor.predict([new_state_var])

    future_reward = self.target_critic.predict([new_state_var, predicted_action])

    Q = reward + self.gamma*future_reward

    self.critic_model.train_on_batch([cur_state_var,  action], Q)


def train_actor(self, samples):

    cur_state_var, action, reward, new_state_var = samples
    predicted_action = self.actor_model.predict([cur_state_var])

    grads = self.sess.run([self.critic_grads], feed_dict={
        self.critic_var_in: cur_state_var,
        self.critic_action_in: predicted_action})

    self.sess.run(self.optimize, feed_dict={
        self.actor_var_in: cur_state_var,
        self.actor_critic_grad: grads[0]
        })

def update_actor_target(self):

    actor_model_weights = self.actor_model.get_weights()
    actor_target_weights = self.target_actor.get_weights()

    for i in range(len(actor_target_weights)):
        actor_target_weights[i] = self.tau * actor_model_weights[i] + (1-self.tau)*actor_target_weights[i]
    self.target_actor.set_weights(actor_target_weights)

def update_critic_target(self):

    critic_model_weights = self.critic_model.get_weights()
    critic_target_weights = self.target_critic.get_weights()

    for i in range(len(critic_target_weights)):
        critic_target_weights[i] = self.tau * critic_model_weights[i] + (1-self.tau)*critic_target_weights[i]
    self.target_critic.set_weights(critic_target_weights)

def update_model(self):

    self.update_actor_target()
    self.update_critic_target()


def act(self, cur_state_var, noise=None, env=None):

    if env:
        if np.random.random() < self.epsilon:
            return env.action_space.sample()

        else:
            sh = cur_state_var.shape
            action = self.actor_model.predict([cur_state_var], batch_size=1)[0]

            return action

    elif not noise:
        if np.random.random() < self.epsilon:
            return self.sample_action_space()
        return self.actor_model.predict([cur_state_var], batch_size=1)[0]
    else:
        no = noise()
        pred = self.actor_model.predict([cur_state_var], batch_size=1)[0]

        return pred + no

def sample_action_space(self):

    return np.array([random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5), random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)]).reshape(2, )

def remember(self, cur_state_var, action, reward, new_state_var):

    self.memory.append([cur_state_var, action, reward,  new_state_var])
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you copy-pasted this code from your editor exactly, but (and this probably isn't your issue, but it's still a problem) the last line of your `train_critic` function is improperly indented. Also, if you're looking for a quick answer, it might be helpful to condense your code to the area you think is problematic. What debugging have you tried already?

Comment: Thank you for your tip! The indent was indeed an issue with pasting the code. As to your second point, I, unfortunately, can't pinpoint the specific area. My best idea of where the mistake might lie is in the actor-network gradient calculation or application. The actions output don't seem to change over time and have very small numerical values.  The self.actor_grads and self.optimize ops in the _init_ method handle these.